# Regex to find and fix unmatched xml closing tags in notepad++

Tags: regex, xml, notepad++

I'm trying to simplify the process of correcting missing unmatched `verse` tags in an xml file that looks like this:

```
    <verse number="21">words words words asdlkjf alsdf. </verse>
    <verse number="22">words words words arbitrary words. 
      <verse number="23">more arbitrary text.</verse>
      <verse number="23">other arbitrary words. </chapter>
```

I would like to use a regex in notepad++ to find the end of a line that starts with an arbitrary number of spaces and `<verse` but does not end with `</verse>`

With the end of the line matched, I should be able use notepad++ find/replace to add the missing tag back in.

Here is what I have so far, which matches every line (the whole line, unfortunately) that starts with spaces and `<verse`

```
^( +<verse).*
```

Comment: The question title should have &lt; and &gt; replaced with `<` and `>`

Comment: Do you want to add the missing end verse tag?

Comment: Does `</chapter>` in the final line need to be maintained?

Comment: @Bohemian Yes, I would like to add the missing closing tags; @trincot Yes, it is important to leave the existing `</chapter>` tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be what you look for:

**Find:** `(^\h+<verse(?!.*verse>\h*).*?)((</.*?>\h*)*)$`
**Replace:** `$1</verse>$2`

Given the sample data it will make two replacements, with this result:

```
    <verse number="21">words words words asdlkjf alsdf. </verse>
    <verse number="22">words words words arbitrary words. </verse>
      <verse number="23">more arbitrary text.</verse>
      <verse number="23">other arbitrary words. </verse></chapter>
```

Comment: Marvelous solution to refer to the matched groups; unfortunately not quite as easy to understand as the solution from @Bohemian; I've accepted it, though, as it is more flexible, where an out of place closing tag may be something other than `</chapter>`

Comment: You're welcome. Indeed the syntax was a bit cluttered because I escaped the `<` and `>` characters, which is in fact not needed (I updated that now). The `\h` represents spaces but also tabs and non-breaking spaces (any white space that is not a new line, but stays "horizontal").

Answer (score 1):

Matching the end of the line is not possible, but you can match the whole line and put it back with the missing end tag:

```
Find: ^ *<verse>(.(?!</verse>))*(</\w*>)?$
Repl: $0</verse>$1
```

Comment: @gdw FYI changed the out-of-place end tag to match *any* non-verse tag.